# Change behaviour of GTK3 mouse cursor using keyboard

Tags: c, mouseover, gtk3, keyboard-events

I am writing a program using C and GTK3+. I want to change the mouse cursor behaviour using the keyboard. At the moment I have code that makes the mouse cursor to change from 'default' to 'crosshair' everytime the mouse hovers the drawing area:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* gcc example_mouse_cursor.c `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 --libs --libs cairo gtk+-3.0` -lm -o example && ./example */

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);


struct {
  int count;
  double coordx[100];
  double coordy[100];
} glob;


static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{
  do_drawing(cr);

  return FALSE;
}


static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.count - 1; i++ ) {
      for (j = 0; j <= glob.count - 1; j++ ) {
          cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[i], glob.coordy[i]);
          cairo_line_to(cr, glob.coordx[j], glob.coordy[j]);
      }
  }

  glob.count = 0;
  cairo_stroke(cr);    
}


static gboolean on_crossing (GtkWidget *darea, GdkEvent *event)
{
  GdkCursor *cursor;
  GdkDisplay *display = gtk_widget_get_display (darea);

  switch (gdk_event_get_event_type (event))
    {
    case GDK_ENTER_NOTIFY:
      cursor = gdk_cursor_new_from_name (display, "crosshair");
      break;

    case GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY:
      cursor = gdk_cursor_new_from_name (display, "default");
      break;
    default:
      break;  
    }
  // Assign the cursor to the window
  gdk_window_set_cursor (gtk_widget_get_window (darea), cursor);

// Release the reference on the cursor
  g_object_unref (cursor);  

  return TRUE;  
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    if (event->button == 1) {
        glob.coordx[glob.count] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[glob.count++] = event->y;
    }

    if (event->button == 3) {
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    }

    return TRUE;
}



gboolean keyboard_press (GtkWidget *window, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data){

  /*Do something if 'b' key is pressed */
  if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_b)
  {
    printf("'b' key pressed!\n");
  }
  return TRUE;     
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;


  glob.count = 0;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_set_has_window (GTK_WIDGET (darea), TRUE);


  gtk_widget_add_events (GTK_WIDGET (darea), (GDK_ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK | GDK_LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK) );
  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect (darea, "enter-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (on_crossing), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (darea, "leave-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (on_crossing), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(window), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK (keyboard_press), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to disable the mouse hovering behaviour ('getting the mouse cursor to just remain 'default' everywhere) when I press the 'b' key. If the user presses the 'b' key again, the cursor-changing bahaviour is once again enabled.

I can get signals from the keyboard working, implemented in the function **gboolean keyboard_press()**, but I have no idea how to change the mouse cursor behaviour from within this function. Is there a way to disconect the signals:

```
g_signal_connect (darea, "enter-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (on_crossing), NULL);
g_signal_connect (darea, "leave-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (on_crossing), NULL);
```

inside the **gboolean keyboard_press()** function? I found [g_signal_handler_disconnect()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-disconnect), but I don't know how to use this.

How would you do this?

Thanks

Comment: `g_signal_handler_disconnect` takes the instance you want to disconnect (`darea`) and the value returned by the `g_signal_connect` call. Why would `enter-notify-event` and `leave-notify-event` have anything to do with pressing "b"?

Comment: Take a look at the [`key-press-event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event). Create a handler which ignores everything but "b", and toggle back and forth between cursors just like you're doing above, only keep track of the current state instead of doing different things depending on which signal you receive.